# I have a checkbox in a list view and I want to know if it is checked or not

Tags: android

I have a list view with the id "lista_pessoas_checkbox" with the items being basically a textfield followed by an checkbox (named "check"), and I want to go through the items to know if the checkboxes are marked or not. This is my current code:

```
ListView listaPessoas = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista_pessoas_checkbox);

for (int i = 0; i < listaPessoas.getAdapter().getCount(); i++){
    View view = (View) listaPessoas.getAdapter().getItem(i);
    if (((CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check)).isChecked()){
        novaParte.getPessoas().add(arrayPessoas.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please put the code on your adapter. It looks like you are saving views inside it, and that is not the way an adapter should works.

Comment: btw, nowadays ListView is not reccommended to use. Better take a look to RecyclerView.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a listener to each property of a listview item. To do so you need to implement your adapter like below:

```
public class X extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {
            private final List<Model> list;
            private final Activity context;

            public InteractiveArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list) {
                super(context, R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, list);
                this.context = context;
                this.list = list;
            }
        publist List<Model> list getList(){
                   return list;}

       public Model getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);}

            static class ViewHolder {
                protected TextView text;
                protected CheckBox checkbox;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = null;
                if (convertView == null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
                    view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, null);
                    final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                    viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
                    viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
                    viewHolder.checkbox
                            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                        boolean isChecked) {
                                    Model element = (Model) viewHolder.checkbox
                                            .getTag();
                                    element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

                                }
                            });
                    view.setTag(viewHolder);
                    viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
                } else {
                    view = convertView;
                    ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
                }
                ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
                holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
                holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
                return view;
            }
        }
```

Here model class would be

```
public class Model {

    private String name;
    private boolean selected;

    public Model(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        selected = false;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

}
```

Now you need to call this adapter on your activity or fragment

```
 ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter = new X(this,
                    getModel());
            setListAdapter(adapter);
```

To get all items at a time just call:

```
 adapter.getList();
```

To get an item by position call:

```
adapter.getItem(position)
```